How to use batch script to launch an Ubuntu terminal with commands for WSL Windows (cd & nvim)
I'm trying to use a batch script to run code files in Neovim inside the Ubuntu terminal, whenever I open a code file using the batch script as the app for Windows.
I can successfully run set "command=nvim \"%file_path%\"" which appends nvim with the file path in order to be run as a command inside the Ubuntu Terminal. This successfully opens the code file inside the Ubuntu Terminal inside neovim.
But I'm running into an issue of where if I use set "command=cd \"%dir_path%\" && nvim \"%file_path%\"", which adds a cd command and then the nvim command, It fails to open the code file.
When the cd command is run by itself and not with the nvim command, the Ubuntu terminal exits right after running.
When the cd command is run with the nvim command, the Ubuntu Terminal is not used to run nvim, but is instead run inside the cmd.exe terminal, which it then displays the following error.
E303: Unable to open swap file for ""\mnt\c\Users\marci\OneDrive\OB", recovery impossible Press ENTER or type command to continue
This is my entire code. You can see some stacks of lines code commented out with rem. That is the other code that I could not get to work / they are for debugging purposes.
@echo off

rem Get file address
set "file_address=%~1"

rem Replace backslashes (\) with forward slashes (/) in file path
set "file_path=%file_address:\=/%"

rem Extract directory path from file path
for %%I in ("%file_path%") do set "dir_path=%%~dpI"

rem Replace backslashes (\) with forward slashes (/) in directory path
set "dir_path=%dir_path:\=/%"

rem Remove trailing backslash from directory path
if "%dir_path:~-1%"=="\" set "dir_path=%dir_path:~0,-1%"

rem Remove first 2 characters (assuming it's the drive letter and backslash)
set "file_path=%file_path:~2%"
set "dir_path=%dir_path:~2%"

rem Prepend /mnt/c/ to the paths to properly reference the C: drive in WSL
set "file_path=/mnt/c%file_path%"
set "dir_path=/mnt/c%dir_path%"

rem Set command to change directory and open file in nvim
rem set "command=cd \"%dir_path%\" && nvim \"%file_path%"\"
rem set "command=cd \"%dir_path%\""
set "command=nvim \"%file_path%\""

rem Copy file & directory path into clipboard
rem echo "%file_path%" | clip
rem echo "%dir_path%" | clip
rem echo "%command%" | clip

rem Launch ubuntu.exe with cmd.exe command
start ubuntu.exe run %command%

I've tried to the best of my knowledge to solve this problem, unfortunately I have no idea where to go from here. I believe my knowledge is flawed or lacking in how to use cd commands using batch script. But I can't find any help out there that solves this.
From my understanding, cd is handled differently in batch script which is why it's not being passed correctly onto Ubuntu terminal. But I don't even know if that's correct.
Can you see where I went wrong? And why it's causing this bug?
I'm so sorry for my ignorance.

Why are you using cmd for this when WSL contains a vastly superior scripting environment?

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

@tripleee You can run it in the wsl terminal? I honestly dont know how to do that.
When I run the script it automatically uses cmd to run. Of course I am ignorant in this topic, so maybe I just dont know how to make it run inside the wsl terminal.
How would you go about in doing this?
I'll do some more research on my end on the meanwhile.
Thank you so much for the help!
I've also removed the images

I fortunately don't have access to Windows at all but I believe you can run commands inside WSL2 like wsl bash -c "echo moo". How to automate your task in Bash instead is obviously way beyond the scope of a single comment; but I believe you'll find that the language is way less crude than cmd batch language.

There're a few problems here:

Path conversion can be improved - \to / can wait until we're done extracting both file and directory:
for /f delims^= %%I in (^""%~dp1."^") do (
    set "file_path=%%~pI\%~nx1"
    set "dir_path=%%~pI"
)
set "file_path=/mnt/c%file_path:\=/%"
set "dir_path=/mnt/c%dir_path:\=/%"


command contains metacharacters (i.e. &) and therefore should be quoted:
start ubuntu.exe run "%command%"


When using quotes with start, the first argument (window title) should be present (it can be empty):
start "" ubuntu.exe run "%command%"


You're using \ to escape quotes, which doesn't work in cmd.exe - here, the symbol for that is ^, as in:
set "command=cd ^"%dir_path^" && nvim ^"%file_path%^""

That, however, is unnecessary - since command itself will be quoted, every character apart from % (and ! should delayed expansion be enabled) will lose its semantics, allowing you to write:
set "command=cd "%dir_path%" && nvim "%file_path%""

This isn't good enough yet; when cmd.exe gets to expand our variable, the command will look like this:
start "" ubuntu.exe run "nvim "%file_path%""

This can (and will) break easily should file_path contain whitespace. Which brings us to the last point:

There's no need to use " here - by that point we'll be on Ubuntu, and therefore can utilize ' for quotes:
set "command=cd '%dir_path%' && nvim '%file_path%'"
start "" ubuntu.exe run "%command%"



Complete script:
@echo off & setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

for /f delims^= %%I in (^""%~dp1."^") do (
    set "file_path=%%~pI\%~nx1"
    set "dir_path=%%~pI"
)
set "file_path=/mnt/c%file_path:\=/%"
set "dir_path=/mnt/c%dir_path:\=/%"

set "command=cd '%dir_path%' && nvim '%file_path%'"
start "" ubuntu.exe run "%command%"

This begs the question: why would you want to do it this way...
